# Test if a large number of whole words appear in a string variable using grepl

Tags: r, regex, match, grepl

I am trying to use `grepl` to test whether a string variable (roughly 30,000 cases) contains any **whole words** from a relatively large list of words (roughly 1,000) words. Here's an example:

```
###create string variable to be tested (note: real data has about 30,000 cases)
string <- c("clayville", "madison", "roberts", "david", "davidson")
df <- data.frame("id" = as.numeric(1:5), "string" = string, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

###create a vector of words to test against string in df (note: real data has aobut 1,000 words)
test <- c("clay", "roberts", "david")
```

Now, I know how to use `grepl` to test if any portion of "test" is contained within "string", as follows:

```
df$test <- grepl(paste(test, collapse = "|"), df$string)
```

That gives the following:

```
id    string  test
1 clayville  TRUE
2   madison  FALSE
3   roberts  TRUE
4     david  TRUE
5  davidson  TRUE
```

Of course, that's not giving me exactly what I want because my code is not accounting for the fact that I am interested in whole words only. For instance, in my sample data, "david" should return TRUE, while "davidson" should return FALSE.

I am familiar with using regular expressions to specify word boundaries, e.g. `\\b`, however, I'm not certain how to do that when I want to conduct so many tests using an OR statement.

What I am really looking for, is the following:

```
id    string  test
1 clayville  FALSE
2   madison  FALSE
3   roberts  TRUE
4     david  TRUE
5  davidson  FALSE
```

Any help y'all could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance, and stay safe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically add word boundaries using `paste0` as :

```
df$test <- grepl(paste0('\\b', test, '\\b', collapse = '|'), df$string)
df
#  id    string  test
#1  1 clayville FALSE
#2  2   madison FALSE
#3  3   roberts  TRUE
#4  4     david  TRUE
#5  5  davidson FALSE
```

Comment: Well, that was easy! Thank you!